# Why does multiple attempts at file creation in PHP fail after first success?

Tags: php

I am writing an installer for someone, and most is going well. If I type everything in correctly the first time, everything is just fine. Upon the database info step, if I type something in incorrectly, I achieve an error as expected, and can correct my error to achieve a successful completion. Now, here's the issue. If some step runs incorrectly, and the user wishes to take a step back, or refresh the browser, the file will not be created. The only way to get the file to create again is to run the install via a fresh window.

File to be created: (Database info - settings.php)
    `<?php
    $dbhot = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "somedude";
    $dbpass = "giggety";
    $dbname = "blah";
    ?>`

Comment: Can you show your code where it writes/updates the file?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen any code in your question. Yet, I brought my crystal ball with me and it says:

Check in your code if a file handler creates a file (an empty file) at the beginning of the execution and that halts your script if already exists. That could explain the fact you can't create it again. Also, that handler probably ignores existing files when you run it all the way from the start point in a fresh window.
Then, your algorithm is to be checked in case it expects something and the error conditions are not properly handled.

That's it. That's all the guessing I can do. If you add code, we all can improve suggestions.